# String.search() vs String.split() and iteration in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, performance, search, split, loops

Lets say I have a string of fruit names

```
var string = "cherries,oranges,limes"
```

and an array of red fruit

```
var array = ["tomatoes", "cherries", "raspberries"]
```

in javascript if I want to find if the string has any red fruit, I can do

```
for(var i=0; i<array.length; i+=1){
    if(string.search(array[i])!=-1){
        return string.search(array[i]);

}
```

How would this compare with the following?

```
var string_array= string.split(','); 
for(var i=0; i<array.length; i+=1){
    for(var j=0; j<string_array.length; j+=1){
       if(string_array[j]==array[i]){
       return string_array[j];
       }
}
}
return -1;
```

Comment: What do you mean "How would this compare" ? You'd like to know what speed difference you'd observe using Chrome's profiler or jsperf ?

Comment: Yes, I meant performance-wise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can't work ;

```
for(var i=0; i<array.length; i+=1){
   return string.search(array[i]);
}
```

You're returning at your first iteration.

So, this wouldn't compare very well.

BTW, if you're interested in script performance comparisons, I suggest you to try using [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/).

Comment: Woops, missed that. Fixed above. Thanks for the recommendation.